# java.lang.StackOverflowError while compiling code using ANT 1.7.1

Tags: java, ant

I am using `ant 1.7.1` to compile my code. While running ant.bat command I am getting following exception even after increasing heap size.

```
An annotation processor threw an uncaught exception.
    [javac] Consult the following stack trace for details.
    [javac] java.lang.StackOverflowError
    [javac]              at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:54)
    [javac]              at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:36)
    [javac]              at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:379)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:348)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField(AST.java:249)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.drill(JavacAST.java:272)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildStatementOrExpression(JavacAST.java:267)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:167)
    [javac]              at lombok.javac.JavacAST.buildTree(JavacAST.java:61)
    [javac]              at lombok.core.AST.buildWithField0(AST.java:351)
```

Comment: Could you share the code snippet with the annotation used.

Answer (score 0):

Check Lombok's version. They had some issue with 0.7.1. Use 0.7.2 or higher.
This error is thrown to indicate that the application’s stack got exhausted due to deep recursion sometimes a never-ending one. 
Ref [Link](https://code.google.com/p/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/detail?id=75).